# Retrieve Current iPhone Lock Screen Live Photo Wallpaper

Tags: iphone, ios, wallpaper

I have an iPhone X running iOS 13.1.2 I currently have a lock screen wallpaper which is a live photo i got from an app when I first got the phone. I no longer have the image saved, and can't find the image again in any app or online. Is there a way to somehow access the current lock screen wallpaper while retaining the Live Photo?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way, but you can take a screen shot while in lock screen.

And if your unlocked screens have the same background, you can create a screen page with only one app on it, and take a screen shot of that.  In fact, when I tried it, I accidentally left the one app on its original page, so the page was empty.

Then use a graphic editor to combine the two, thereby removing much of the clock and the app icon.

I took the top half of the empty app page (no big clock) and the bottom half of the empty app page (no dock) to get the image below.

Then if you put the resulting image into reverse image search, you **might** get the original image.

[image]

Comment: I tried it with the image I created.  Found an image that had no text except a tiny bit of Chinese on the bottom edge.  It was positioned so that I could erase it by pasting part of my image.  But there's no guarantee OP's image will be found the same way.

Comment: @Theologin, that should be a comment on the question, not on my answer.